# Recursive navigation function in PHP (mssql -> sqlsrv problem)

Tags: php, sql-server, recursion

Our site has a function that grabs all of the navigation items and the sub navigation items as follows:

```
function setNav($sectionID = 0) {
  $divs = $db->getData("SELECT * 
                          FROM table 
                         WHERE Section = ".$sectionID);
  foreach ($divs as $div) {
    $subArray = setNav($div['ID']);
    $thisArray[$div['ID']]['ID'] = $div['ID'];
    $thisArray[$div['ID']]['Title'] = $div['Title'];
    $thisArray[$div['ID']]['Children'] = $subArray;
  }

  return $thisArray;
}
```

It worked fine when we used the mssql_ functions, but since switching to a new version of PHP where that is depreciated, it's throwing up an error saying:

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting
>   level of '100' reached, aborting!

Comment: What version of SQLServer do you use? 2005 introduces recursive CTE, so you can issue just 1 query.

Comment: Am using SQL2005! Will Google recursive CTE now, thanks :) (edit: hmm, slightly confusing stuff! heh. will have to take this home with me tonight and have a good read I think ^_^)

Comment: I added an answer with how your query can look like. Hope it helps.

Comment: Crap, just realised it's not SQL 2005, that's just the editor I'm using! :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This limit is set by xdebug. Check your php.ini and comment out the line that loads the xdebug library and then restart your web server.

Beyond that, you may wish to refactor your code to use nested sets in the future.

Comment: Many thanks for this, will comment out that line as a last resort - at least it'll work then, ty :)

Comment: heh, tried disabling xdebug - Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261904 bytes) - oops!

Comment: Add some `print_r` statements for debugging purposes. Chances are you have infinite recursion going on. Also add a counter variable to `getData` and echo it out to see how many times it's being called.

Answer (score 2):

That message is coming from PHP, because you recursed into setNav too many times.

Unless you've got a navigation tree that ends up a hundred entries deep, I suspect something might be going wrong with your call to getData.

Can you make sure that it's returning valid entries?

Also, as a1ex07 says, you might be best using some kind of recursive query, rather than recursive calls to the non-recursive query, if possible.

Comment: It's not 100 deep, but there are probably 100 different records... hmm? Will look into that, thank you!

Comment: But 100 nested entries would cause this failure.  If you don't have 100, chances are your getData() is returning an array, but one that doesn't contain valid data, so your recursive function never meets its termination condition (ie empty array returned from getData)

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server 2005 and higher you can write something like this :

```
$divs = $db->getData(" 
WITH tableCTE AS  
  (SELECT * 
    FROM table 
    WHERE Section = ".$sectionID. "
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT t2.* FROM tableCTE t1
    INNER JOIN table t2 ON (t2.id = t1.Section)
   )
 SELECT * FROM tableCTE
  "
);
```

Comment: Crap, just realised it's not SQL 2005, that's just the editor I'm using! :O